# Hosting WCF service library in IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis-7

**In My Computer A (Running XP)**

**Step 1)** I created a **WCF service library** and coded it (On F5 it runs fine the endpoint generated is        `http://localshost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CustomService/Service1/`

**Step 2)** I added a Asp.Net (TestWebSite) website to it and then added service reference to above file (On f5 the service is runnning so is the client ,everything is proper)

**In My Computer B (Running Win7)**

**Step 1)** I installed IIS 7, as a result a default website is created at port 80

**Step 2)** I added my  TestWebSite at port 81 to IIS and i can view my site in the browser

Now how can I access my WCF service on IIS 7?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

Comment: Try these things

`1. Ping your computer A and B
 2. Try with replacing localhost with proper IP.
 3. Check your firewall whether it blocking connection on specified port.`

Answer (score 1):

1)Right Click your Solution Explorer.
2)click on Publish 
3)Choose Hosting Folder and press Publish Button
4) Open Intetmgr.exe from Run prompt
5) Add New WebApplication and bind with the publish Folder.
6) Right Click on WebAPplication-> Browse
7)type in url "http://application:5856/serives.svc"
8) Copy the link from the page displayed

Comment: There is no Publish option in a WCF Service Library project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Computer A can talk to Computer B. That is they are in the same domain. And assuming that you want to create a service reference to the site on computer A from computer B.

You can access your service by:

```
  http://hostname:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CustomService/Service1/
```

Here hostname is the name of the machine in your case Computer A. If you wan to find your hostname you can go to command line and type hostname and press enter. This should work. If i got what you are trying to achive.

Comment: are you on the same domain? can you ping computer A from computer B?